# error al generar un meme en un Bot de dicord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
      request = await session.get('https://some-random-api.ml/meme') # Make a request
      dogjson = await request.json() # Convert it to a JSON dictionary
   embed = discord.Embed(title="texto", color=random.choice(colors)) 
   embed.set_image(url=dogjson['link'])
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

> Error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised
> an exception: KeyError: 'link'

Comment: ¿Alguna pregunta?

Comment: Es un bot no una IA, ¿que esperas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key error sale cuando estas tratando de acceder a una llave del diccionario que no existe. En este caso `link` no seria la llave correcta.

Si vas a `https://some-random-api.ml/meme` y ves el json que te da:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "image": "https://i.some-random-api.ml/GN4W3gcnXV.png",
    "caption": "About time I took steps",
    "category": "random"
}
```

Veras que tiene que ser `image`, no `link`.